Nextjs redirection in middleware is going haywire
OK So, in my Next14 project (w/ Strapi backend - unrelated) I have set up middleware stacking because I needed middleware for i18 purposes and also for auth purposes (Auth.js / next-auth v5) -- normal stuff
Here's a gist with the appropriate files so I don't fill this post with codeblocks.
localeMiddleware.ts, authMiddleware.ts and stackHandler.ts are in /middlewares,
middleware.ts and routes.ts are in /src
Followed this SO answer for implementation of middleware stacking.
So, the localeMiddleware, among other things, are supposed to check the route, and if it is not an api route and it doesn't have a locale (/en or /el) it's supposed to add it (so, / would become /en/ or /el/, /contact -> /en/contact or /el/contact etc...
That works fine (other than it used to keep the locale info as a cookie for later use - I have somehow managed to remove that part of the code but I'll figure that out later, since currently nothing seems to work and that one is the least of my concerns rn
The issue is (I think?) with the authMiddleware, where they're supposed to redirect users besed on their loggedIn status (bool) and the route they're trying to access
so, for examlple (and in order of check since it matters):
regardless of loggedIn status, if the route is an auth api, no redirects should be happening, since those need to remain publically accessible for auth purposes (..duh)
Then, if it's an auth route and the user is loggedIn, they're supposed to be redirected to /settings (and then the locale middleware would theoretically kick in and change the route to /en/settings or /el/settings
If the user is not logged in, don't redirect (since we want them to be able to access /login, /signup etc for auth purposes
Then, if the user is NOT loggedIn and they're trying to access a private route (eg. /settings), they should be redirected to /login (subsequently /en/login or /el/login) in order to be auth'ed.
If none of the above are happening, it means the user - whether loggedIn or not - is trying to access a public route (eg. /contact) which we should allow.
The current issue is, as the code stands, trying to access any route, like / or /contact using any locale or none at all, the user is taken to /en/login, then to /en//login, then to /login and then back from the start, in an infinite redirect loop, which Firefox detects and shuts down with the following error:
The page isn’t redirecting properly

Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will
never complete.

    This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies.

(fun fact trying to redirect to auth/login takes the user to http://localhost:3000/en/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/auth/login -- in case the info tells someone with more experience than me something useful about the issue)
So far I've tried changing the redirect routes (eg. /en/login, /el/login with localeMiddleware removed so it wouldn't redirect to /en/en/login, removing and adding different rules, removing localeMiddleware, adding /en and /el to routes.ts (see below), all to no avail
routes.ts file with added /en and /el routes:
/**
 * An array of routes that are accessible to the public.
 * These routes do not require authentication.
 * @type {string[]}
 */

export const publicRoutes = [
    "/",
    "/blog",
    "/contact",
    "/portfolio",
    "/pricing",
    "/services",
    "/en/",
    "/en/blog",
    "/en/contact",
    "/en/portfolio",
    "/en/pricing",
    "/en/services",
    "/el/",
    "/el/blog",
    "/el/contact",
    "/el/portfolio",
    "/el/pricing",
    "/el/services",
];

/**
 * An array of routes that are used for authentication.
 * These routes will redirect logged in users to /settings.
 * @type {string[]}
 */
export const authRoutes = [
    "/auth/login",
    "/auth/signup",
    "/en/auth/login",
    "/en/auth/signup",
    "/el/auth/login",
    "/el/auth/signup",
];


/**
 * The prefix for api authentication routes.
 * Routes that start with this prefix are used for api auth purposes.
 * @type {string}
 */
export const apiAuthPrefix = "/api/auth";

/**
 * The deafult redirect path after logging in.
 * @type {string}
 */
export const DEFAULT_LOGIN_REDIRECT = "/settings"

I honestly don't know what else I should try and change to see if it works - will keep trying stuff and updating the post if anything changes, but I could really use the help or at least some pointers from the community
Thanks in advance ^^ <3
